# Raspberry Pi Network Drive, access denied after reboot - how to fix?

Tags: raspbian-wheezy

I have set up a shared drive on my Pi, but when it get's rebooted, I have to use remote desktop to log in to the pi, before computers can start connecting to the drive again.

Is there anyway I can fix it so if the pi gets turned off, computers can still connect to it without me having to fire up remote desktop to login to the pi?

I want to be able to power the pi down, and only have it turned on when the computers on the network auto-backup... I will be using a timer switch to the the pi on and off.

Comment: Just out of interest, how are you running the power-off timer? You can't just yank the power from a linux machine and expect the data on the drives to survive. It needs to be shut down in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit /etc/fstab - the file which determines which file systems are mounted at boot.

I wrote guide to set up your Pi as a NAS, which includes automatically mounting shared drives using Samba at boot - the process should also apply to your project. You can [read it here](http://bigcowpi.blogspot.com/2013/03/raspbery-pi-wireless-auto-sorting.html), or if you don't want to visit my blog a google search for 'fstab' should get you heading in the right direction :)

Comment: I have 2 drives when I go to \\raspberrypi one called `pi` and the other which is my drive `USB` .. the folder `pi` opens fine but `usb` can only be accessed if I use remote desktop and login to the pi itself... if I attach my `smb.conf` can you take a look?

Comment: FIXED! Made adjustments so it auto logs in and goes to `startx` thanks for your suggestion